# Does treating a string as a character array return an "Uninitialized string offset" notice?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm getting the following notice

`Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in /script.php on line 17`

Here are lines 16 and 17

```
$results = exec('ping -c 1 -w 1 ' . $ip, $output);
$servers[] = ($results[1] === '' ? false : true);
```

Is this being caused by me using `$results[1]` to get the second character of $results? If so, reading on the internet, it appears `$string[]` is recommended over `substr()` so why does it generate a notice?

My script relies on this file to generate JSON, so a notice breaks it (and this is an issues since it's an open source script)

Comment: That means the returned string has less than 2 characters.

Comment: How could one character equal to an empty string anyway?

Comment: @Cthulhu if the server is online, the second character in the result is not a space. If it's offline, there is a space.

I guess I should be checking if $results is an empty string, as opposed to the second character then? And `$string[]` returns an error if no character exists in that position, while `substr()` would return false?

Comment: @cantsay In your code sample there is a comparison with empty string, not a space but anyway I get an idea.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. I must have decided to check if it was a string that way, and overlooked the fact arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` returns a string.  To access each character in the string you can use the array notation `$string[x]` like `$string[1]` starting from `0`.  However, if there are 0 or 1 characters then `[1]` doesn't exist.  It appears you are just checking the string as you are checking `''`.  Use one of the following:

```
$servers[] = $results ? true : false;
//or
$servers[] = ($results === '') ? true : false;
```

Based on your comment, to check for the character position and a space:

```
$servers[] = (isset($results[1]) && $results[1] === ' ') ? false : true;
//or
$servers[] = (strpos($results, ' ') === 1) ? false : true;
```

I would use `strpos`.

Comment: thanks for explaining, but should it be `$servers[] = ($results ? true : false);` (false and true reversed)?

Comment: Depends on the logic.  I just saw your comment and added test for 2nd character.

Comment: I think this is the case where `@$result[1] === ' '` is really appropriate.